# JQuery assigning top to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a html tag like below

```
<div id='myDiv' style="top: 300px, position: absolute"></div>
```

On some event I want to give it top 200px.I am doing like this

```
$('#myDiv').css('top','200px');
```

But it is not assigning the desire top. I guess in line styling has more precedence.

Comment: `.css()` modifies inline css, check what you get in inspection.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<div id='myDiv' style="top: 300px; position: absolute"></div>
                                 ^ ; is used to separate
```

instead of

```
<div id='myDiv' style="top: 300px, position: absolute"></div>
                                 ^ not comma
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#myDiv').css('top', '200px');
$('#myDiv').append(function(){ return $(this).css('top'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv' style="top: 300px; position: absolute">Hello</div>
```